# location of custom plist file

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, plist

I have created a plist file for my App. 2 questions:

1) If I have added the plist file to the Xcode project, will the file get automatically bundled and distributed with the App?

2) The Simulator always seems to 'locate' the file upon startup. Even if I manually remove the file from the App's root folder. This is where the Simulator is looking for the file:

```
/Users/Joe/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/28C13BB3-xxxx....
```

Where should my plist file be located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes. If Xcode project lists the file, it will be automatically bundled and distributed.

2) You can place your plist file anywhere under the top level project folder. Everything under your top level folder is your project bundle.

What do you mean when you say you remove the file from app's root folder ?

Comment: By root folder I mean the folder where the App is placed after it is built:

    /Users/Joe/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/28C13BB3-xxxx....

Comment: When you make (or run) your build, it checks for the existence of all files in the build directory and copies from the bundle if anything is missing. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks vipinagg. Unsure if it helps. I am not seeing the .plist file in Apps folder or its children, Yet the App is finding it. (see my recent comment above).

Comment: Locate the file in the project in Xcode and remove it by pressing delete (don't move it trash, just remove the reference). Clean and re-build.

Comment: That worked! I didn't realize the app is actually a folder which contains the plist file in it (see Oscar's thread below). However, the Clean/Rebuild didn't quite work: the original plist file was not removed from the App. I needed to manually delete the file from App using Finder. Then did a Clean/Rebuild and the plist file could not be found by the App. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes it will as long as it is in the Target/Build Phases/Copy bundle resources.

2) It will be located on your application documents directory, you don't really need to worry about it, except you have to add the file to your project and make sure number 1 of this list has been done.

The simulator finds it even after remove, because it keeps state, unless you manually reset the simulator. Therefore it already had a copy of the file in the folder you mention, even if you removed it.

Comment: You don't have to reset the simulator.  You can simply remove the app, the same way you would uninstall an app on a real device - hold down on the icon in Springboard until it starts wiggling, then tap the X button to delete it.

Comment: OK, I verified my .plist file is in the Target/Build Phases/Copy Bundle Resources.

I then removed the App from the Simulator using @rob's suggestion above.

However the App is still finding the file. When printing the file location, this is what I get:

    /Users/Joe/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/B3484717-91DF-407A-A52A-68E565418914/Affirmations.app/AffirmationList.plist


Since I cannot see the file in the '...8914' folder or any of its children, Does that mean the .plist file is actually **inside** Affirmations.app?

Comment: An app is actually a folder.  You can open the folder in the Finder by right-clicking it (or control-clicking it) and choosing Show Package Contents.

Comment: OK, I didn't know that. This is very helpful. Sure enough, the plist file is in the 'App'